# Uninstalling packages and package "cache"

Tags: apt, sudo

Long story short, this is mostly out of curiosity, I typed `gb` and I received the `The program 'gb' is not installed.  You can install it by typing: 'sudo apt install gb'`.  I did that, it installed, but it wasn't the right version, so I used `sudo apt remove gb` to uninstall it.

Now, let's say I need it again.  I type `gb` and no longer does it say `The program 'gb' is not installed. You can install it...`.  What do I have to do in order to start getting that message again?

Comment: Read `man apt`, and do something like `sudo apt purge gb`, `sudo apt autoremove`, `type -p gb`, ...

Comment: I'd sooner guess you did something inbetween like changed your repos or ran apt-get update.